# Flutter App Video Files Getting Deleted on Xiaomi Redmi Devices

Tags: android, flutter, caching, xiaomi

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I've encountered a perplexing issue with my Flutter apps, and I'm seeking some guidance to understand and resolve this problem. The situation involves video files saved within the **android/data** folder, and it appears that on certain **Redmi** devices, these video files are mysteriously getting deleted after a device restart. This issue is not present on all devices, and I've conducted some testing to gather relevant information.

**Devices Where Video Files Got Deleted:**

Redmi Note 10 Pro
Android Version: 12
MIUI Version: 13

Redmi Note 11
Android Version: 13
MIUI Version: 14.0.3

Redmi Note 10
Android Version: 12
MIUI Version: 14.0

Redmi 10
Android Version: 13
MIUI Version: 14.0.4

Redmi 10c
Android Version: 13
MIUI Version: 14

Redmi 10 Pro Max
Android Version: 13
MIUI Version: 14.0.1

Redmi Note 9
Android Version: 12
MIUI Version: 13

Redmi Note 9 Pro
Android Version: 12
MIUI Version: 14.0.2

**Devices Where Video Files Are Not Deleted:**

Redmi 7 Pro
Android Version: 10
MIUI Version: 12.5.1

Poco X2
Android Version: 11
MIUI Version: 12.5.6

Poco M3 Pro 5G
Android Version: 11
MIUI Version: 12.0.2

Redmi Note 9s
Android Version: 12
MIUI Version: 14.5

**And in any other android branded phone everything is working fine!**

I'm puzzled by this inconsistency and wondering if anyone else has encountered a similar issue or has insights into why this might be happening specifically on these Xiaomi Redmi devices. Could it be related to certain MIUI versions or Android versions?

Any help, advice, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I tried looking in the Android Logcat, Device cleaner, and optimisers which Xiaomi Provides and everything is working fine, and every setting is correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know why my video files are getting deleted? I am saving them without extension, like if the file name is "video.mp4", I am saving them as "video" then while playing I am adding .mp4.